# switch(true) vs. if(true) doesn't return the same (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm writing a function for when a button is clicked. There are plenty of different buttons, so I'd like to use a `switch(true)` statement as opposed to a long series of `if...else if` statements.

Several of the buttons are for numbers and I've put the number in the `value` attribute of the `<button>` tag. However, testing these two functions gives different results.

```
switch(true) {
    case (Number(button.value)):
        console.log('thats a number');
        break;
    default:
        console.log('NaN');
        break;
}

if(Number(button.value)) {
    console.log('thats a number');
} else {
    console.log('NaN');
}
```

Can someone please explain why? I've tested thoroughly without getting anywhere and feel like it must be some technical difference in the way `switch` and `if` statements are processed.

Comment: `switch(true)` will always result in the same case due to it is not a variable but a hardcoded `true` value

Comment: "*I'd like to use a switch(true) statement as opposed to a long series of if...else if statements.*" - please don't. The `switch(true)` statement will neither be shorter nor more efficient, only more weird and error-prone (as you noticed). If at all, you should switch by the button identifier. But of course, if there are many different buttons doing different things, you should just write different event handlers instead of a single big one.

Answer (score 7):

The [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) checks the given condition with [strict equality `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity), whereas `if` takes a value which is converted to boolean for a check.

What you get in `switch` is

```
true === Number(button.value)
```

and that check is never `true`